# Windows Mobile cordova/phonegap style and events

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, windows-mobile

I am building a cordova/phonegap hybrid app, in it I am using some libraries: I choosed them by compatibility.

- jQuery 1.12.3
- JQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Both of them should be completely supported by IE/Edge and then from WM applications.

My problem is quite simple: my app shows in a wrong way (like is does not load some css correctly) and does not capture touch events on buttons. The application works on Android. If I put /www directory directly on my phone and open it with Edge, it works.

I have found on the net that a lot of problems may came from config.xml, so I am going to paste it there:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.univaq.disim.helpme" version="1.0.0">
  <name>HelpMe</name>
  <description>HelpMe is an application geolocalized cross-platform for disaster management</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="2.1.0" source="pgb" />
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
        <!-- icons -->
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
        <!-- icons -->        
  </platform>
</widget>
```

What may be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that PhoneGap compiler is not updated so compiled XAP files from it does not work very good (or at all) on Windows 10 Mobile (can't tell about Windows Phone).

As a general suggestion, when faced a similar issue, is a good advise to try to compile it by hand with Cordova cli (or a Cordova automated compiler as Visual Studio) with latest tool, it should solve lot of panic.

Hope this may help others!